# Can you make total height for a 3-div-sandwhich equal 100% if top & bottom divs are in pixels?

Tags: html, css, website-design, design, cross-browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any problems with DIVs inside a table cell?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/13418/any-problems-with-divs-inside-a-table-cell)

Ok so I've got a header and a footer with absolute positioning and heights of 144px. The content div in the middle area needs to be the full height of the area in between.

Simplified:

```
<style>
  .sandwich{
    position: absolute;
    height: 144px; 
    width: 100%; 
    left: 0;
  }
  #header{ top:    0px; }
  #footer{ bottom: 0px; }
</style>

<div id="header" class="sandwich"></div>
<div id="content"> Content </div>
<div id="footer" class="sandwich"></div>
```

So basically I want a div that is 100% - 288px. At first I thought I could just make a 100% x 100% div with 144 padding on top and bottom and then stuff the content div in there at 100% but my thinking has gone stray somewhere.

[image]

> Here's an example I made using 20% height for 'bread layers'. (Which I can't do on this project) Used 60% height for the scrolling 'meaty layer' and put it at top: 20%;

Comment: [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910227/any-problems-with-divs-inside-a-table-cell/5910995#5910995) on a migrated question. If anyone can provide something similar or if possible better after seeing the correct result, I can accept an answer but atm neither of these is really what I asked about sry.

Comment: Merging per request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add the following CSS:

```
html, body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#content{
  position: absolute; 
  top: 144px; 
  bottom: 144px; 
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto; 
}
```

And presto.

Comment: No one was answering after I had the answer from related question on SE so..after posting the link and waiting, I put it up.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like no matter what, you're wanting the footer to be at the very bottom of the screen, even if there's no content in between the header and footer. Is this accurate? If so, you're looking for a "sticky footer" solution. There's tons of methods out there, you can give this one a try to start off with: [CssStickyFooter](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/).

Comment: This is somewhat close, I can make a sticky footer fairly easily though I'm really liking the way they're implementing this on resize =D You could say what I've got is a sticky header and a sticky footer. The main overflow is disabled letting the content div in the middle handle the scrollbar.

Answer (score 1):

Use `position:fixed` and `z-index:10` on the `.sandwich` class to keep your header and footer static above the `#content` div, then style the `body` to get your background red colour to fill the space between. [Live demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/4bHsm/2/)

```
<style>

    body{
        background-color:red;
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
    }

    .sandwich{
        position:fixed;
        height: 50px;
        width: 100%; 
        background-color:grey;
        z-index:10;
    }

    #header{ top: 0px;}
    #footer{ bottom: 0px;}

    #content{ position:absolute; top:50px; }  
</style>

<div id="header" class="sandwich"></div>
<div id="content"> Content goes here</div>
<div id="footer" class="sandwich"></div>
```

Comment: Well again this is close but not quite. See how the lower part of body get's cut off by the footer if you scroll all the way down? This is the same issue I'm having on my closest attempt. Just to reiterate, the main goal is to have the scrollbar exist only for the content's overflow so I need a div that can change size to (100% - [headerHeight + footerHeight])

Comment: To prevent the cutoff, you can add `padding-bottom:50px` to the `#content` div: http://jsfiddle.net/4bHsm/3/ I'd recommend against inset scrollbars; they are both ugly and frustrating to use, mostly because they're not widely adopted as a page scrolling method on other websites. There are times when nested scrollbars *are* useful, but I'd suggest that this isn't one of them.